# File system Python - import not working

Tags: python, import, path, filesystems

I have a Python script in a file stored in a Folder MyFolder. Tree structure for the file system is the following

```
MyFolder
    - Image
          - scipt_image.py
    - script.py
    - script_test.py
```

I want to use scripts in Image, scipt_image.py, in script script.py. To include this script_image.py, I use this :

```
import os, sys
DATA_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Image'))
sys.path.append(DATA_DIR)
```

Then, i import script_image.py, with

```
import scipt_image
```

From errors at compilation, this seems not be working. However, problem may come from something else. Does this sounds correct ?

thanks

Comment: There is a typo, do you mean `import script_image`?

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you don't simply use the `Image` folder as a python package and import the file directly without messing with sys.path?

I would simply turn `Image` into a [python package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (create an empty file named `__init__.py` in `Image`) and then import `script_image` like this:

```
from Image import script_image
```